# Finding the expected value of $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$

Tags: probability, integration, multivariable-calculus

Below is a problem from the Schaum book on Probability and Statistics. I did part a right but my answer for part b is wrong. I am hoping somebody can
tell me where I went wrong.
Thanks,
Bob

Problem:

Let $X$ and $Y$ have join density function:
$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
cxy & \text{for } 0 < x < 1, 0 < y < 1\\
0 & otherwise \\
\end{cases} \\
$$
Find (a) $E(X^2 + Y^2)$, (b) $E(\sqrt{X^2+Y^2})$.
Answer: (a)
The first thing we need to do is find $c$.
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 \int_0^1 cxy \, dy \, dx &= 1 \\
\int_0^1 \frac{cx}{2} \, dx &= 1 \\
\frac{c}{4} &= 1 \\
c &= 4 \\
E(X^2 + Y^2) &= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 4xy(x^2+y^2) \, dy \, dx \\
E(X^2 + Y^2) &= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 4x^3y + 4xy^3 \, dy \, dx \\
E(X^2 + Y^2) &= \int_0^1  2x^3y^2 + xy^4 \,\Big{|}_{y = 0}^{y=1} dx \\
E(X^2 + Y^2) &= \int_0^1 2x^3 + x \, dx = \frac{2x^4}{4} + \frac{x^2}{2} \Big{|}_0^1 = \frac{2}{4} + \frac{1}{2} \\
E(X^2 + Y^2) &= 1 \\
\end{align*}
Part (b)
\begin{align*}
E(\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}) &= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 4xy \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \, dy \, dx \\
\end{align*}
Now we use the substitution $u_1 = x^2 + y^2$ with $du_1 = 2y_1 dy$.
\begin{align*}
E(\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}) &= \int_0^1 \int_{x^2}^{x^2+1} 2xu_1 \sqrt{u_1} \, du_1 \, dx =
 \int_0^1 \int_{x^2}^{x^2+1} 2xu_1^{\frac{3}{2}} \, du_1 \, dx \\
E(\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}) &=  \int_0^1 \frac{2xu_1^{ \frac{5}{2} }}{\frac{5}{2}} \Big{|}_{u_1 = x^2}^{u_1 = x^2 + 1} \, dx =
  \int_0^1 \frac{4xu_1^{ \frac{5}{2} }}{5} \Big{|}_{u_1 = x^2}^{u_1 = x^2 + 1} \, dx \\
E(\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}) &= \int_0^1 \frac{4x(x^2+1)^\frac{5}{2}}{5} - \frac{4x(x^2)^\frac{5}{2}}{5} \, dx \\
\int_0^1 \frac{4x(x^2)^\frac{5}{2}}{5} \, dx  &= \int_0^1 \frac{4x^6}{5} \, dx = \frac{4x^7}{35} \Big|_0^1 \\
\int_0^1 \frac{4x(x^2)^\frac{5}{2}}{5} \, dx  &= \frac{4}{35} \\
\end{align*}
Now we need to perform the following integration:
$$ \int_0^1 \frac{4x(x^2+1)^\frac{5}{2}}{5} \, dx  $$
\newline
To perform this integration, we use the substitution $u_2 = x^2 + 1$.
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 \frac{4x(x^2+1)^\frac{5}{2}}{5} \, dx  &= \int_1^2 \frac{ 2u^{\frac{5}{2} } }{5} \, du_2 \\
\int_0^1 \frac{4x(x^2+1)^\frac{5}{2}}{5} \, dx  &= \frac{2u^{ \frac{7}{2} }}{ \frac{5(7)} {2 }} \Big{|}_1^2 \\
\int_0^1 \frac{4x(x^2+1)^\frac{5}{2}}{5} \, dx  &= \frac{4u^{ \frac{7}{2} }}{ 35 } \Big{|}_1^2 \\
\int_0^1 \frac{4x(x^2+1)^\frac{5}{2}}{5} \, dx  &= \frac{4 (2^\frac{7}{2})}{35} - \frac{4}{35} \\
E(\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}) &= \frac{4 (2^\frac{7}{2})}{35} - \frac{4}{35} - \frac{4}{35} \\
E(\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}) &= \frac{ 32 \sqrt{2} - 8 }{35}  \\
E(\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}) &= \frac{8(4 \sqrt{2} - 1)}{35}  \\
\end{align*}
However, the book's answer is:
$$ \frac{8(2 \sqrt{2} - 1)} {15} $$

Comment: I get $\int\limits_{x=0}^1 \frac{4 x (x^2+1)^{5/2}}{5}\ dx =\frac{4}{35} \left(8 \sqrt{2}-1\right)$, not what the book states.  If the book is right, your normalization constant is off.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Your answer matches the OP's answer for that part of the calculation. However, I don't see how this is "half what the book states", e.g., it has a denominator of $15$ while both you and the OP have $35$.

Comment: I now get the book's answer:  $\int\limits_0^1 \int\limits_0^1 4 x y \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} dx\ dy = \frac{8}{15} \left(2 \sqrt{2}-1\right)$.

Comment: I believe my value for $c$ is correct because my answer for part a is correct.

Comment: @Bob Your value for $c$ is correct. However, I missed an error in my earlier comment that it all looked correct. After you do your initial substitution, you say that $E(\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}) = \int_0^1 \int_{x^2}^{x^2+1} 2xu_1 \sqrt{u_1} \, du_1 \, dx$. However, you should not have the $u_1$ factor there. Removing this will give you a $u_1$ power of $1/2$, not $3/2$, so on integration you will get a power of $3/2$, not $5/2$, with this resulting eventually in a denominator of $15$, not $35$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Could you post how you computed that double integral?

Comment: @Bob Using $u_1 = x^2 + y^2$ and $du_1 = 2ydy$ means that in $4xy\sqrt{x^2+y^2}dy$, the $2ydy$ becomes $du_1$ and $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ becomes $\sqrt{u_1}$, so overall it becomes $2x \sqrt{u_1} \, du_1$, not $2xu_1 \sqrt{u_1} \, du_1$. Making this change and then doing basically the same rest of calculations you did will result in the appropriate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too many subscripts spoil the math.  Keep the distractions to a minimum.

But anyway, your error looks to be an improper substitution.  If $u=x^2+y^2$ (for a fixed $x$), then $\mathsf du=2y\mathsf dy$ .

$${\mathsf E(\sqrt{X^2+Y^2})
\\ = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cdot 4xy~\mathsf d y~\mathsf d x
\\ = \int_0^1 2x\int_0^1 \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cdot 2y\mathsf d y~\mathsf d x
\\= \int_0^1 2x\int_{x^2}^{1+x^2} \sqrt{u}~\mathsf d u~\mathsf d x \qquad:u=x^2+y^2, u\in[x^2;1+x^2]\quad\bigstar
\\= \int_0^1 2x\left[\tfrac 23 u^{3/2}\right]_{u=x^2}^{u=1+x^2}~\mathsf d x
\\= \int_0^1 \tfrac 43 x\left((1+x^2)^{3/2}-x^3\right)~\mathsf d x
\\= \tfrac 43\int_0^1 x(1+x^2)^{3/2}-x^4~\mathsf d x
\\= \tfrac 23\int_0^1 (1+x^2)^{3/2}\cdot 2x\mathsf dx-\tfrac 4{15} x^5\vert_{x=0}^{x=1}
\\= \tfrac 23\int_1^2 (v)^{3/2}\cdot \mathsf dv-\tfrac 4{15}\qquad:v=x^2+1,v\in[1;2]
\\= \tfrac 23\tfrac 25 (v)^{5/2}\vert_{v=1}^{v=2}-\tfrac 4{15}
\\= \tfrac 4{15} (2^{5/2}-1)-\tfrac 4{15}
\\= \tfrac 8{15} (2^{3/2}-1)
\\= \tfrac 8{15} (2\surd 2-1)
}$$